# React higher-order-component rest vs props

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-props

I was wondering what the difference was in props & rest here and if I need to include them both when rendering my component(`<Component {...rest} {...props} />`)

```js
const ProtectedRoute = ({
  component: Component
  ...rest
}: ProtectedRouteProps): ReactElement => {
  // redirect logic here

  return (
    <Route {...rest} render={(props) => <Component {...rest} {...props} />} />
  )
}
```

Comment: Tangential, but maybe you could check the value of `props` and `rest` and see what the diff, if any, is (delta that a single check might not be exhaustive).

Comment: `rest` are the props that are passed from wherever to `ProtectedRoute` and `props` are the props passed from `Route` to `Component`. As to if you need both, the question is more if you want both. They are most likely not the same but contain different things.

Answer (score 1):

`...rest` is based on arguments, and needs to be at the end of your parameters.  It has to do with `functions` and not so much as `props`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters